# What is the sum of all the $4$ digit numbers formed with the digits $1,3,3$ and $0$?

Tags: permutations, combinations

What is the sum of all the $4$ digit numbers formed with the digits $1,3,3$ and $0$?

The only problem is related to the repeated digits here and the "0".

Please help and solve it for a general case so that I can solve any question of this type.

P.S.,  I am a JEE(Joint Entrance Examination) aspirant.

Comment: Zero can be at any place but the first one. Use that fact and then find the sum normally.

Comment: Welcome to Math. SE.  You are required to show your efforts here when you ask a question. Also, the community here is worldwide and may not understand what JEE means. (It if an entrance exam for all the IITs and some other good schools in India for undergrad study)

Answer (score 2):

This is a small problem, you can easily enumerate, but I am giving a general way to solve.

There are $4!/2! = 12$ permutations of $1,3,3,0$ if you allow $0$ at the first place.

Each **column** will have $6\;\; 3's, 3\;\; 1's$ and $3\;\; 0's$ totaling to 21, so the sum $= 21 + 210 + 2100$

Now subtract $3$ digit numbers having $1,3,3$ with $3!/2!$ = 3 permutations,  totalling to $7$ per column, sum $= 7+70+700$

i.e. ans $= (21 + 210 + 2100) - (7 + 70 + 700)$

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, let us start with a number 'abcd'. We have 4! possible permutations.

However, if we have the number 'abbc', each of the permutations is a duplicate, e.g. abbc=abbc with the two 'b's swapped round. So we have (4!)/2=8 possible permutations. If we carry on investigating, e.g. with 'abbb', we have three duplicates of each permutation. So then, we only have four possible permutations. To keep this short, I'll omit my method of working this out, but let n be the number of duplicate permutations deleted. In a number like 'aaaabbb', we have three duplicate 'a's and two duplicate 'b's. n would then be equal to 2^3 (for the 'a's) + 2^2 (for the 'b's).

Let the number of digits our number is be l. Our formula for the number of permutations is (l!)-n, where you work out n as I explained.

With our number, 1330, now, we have a zero. This makes things slightly more complicated, as a number cannot start with 0. To overcome this, we shall make a new number, without the zeroes, i.e. 133, and work out how many possible permutations there are. Then, subtract the number of permutations for the number without zeroes from the number of permutations from our whole number. This removes all possible permutations that start with 0.

Note that this solution does not quite answer your question, because it works out the number of permutations, not the sum of the permutations - but I think you can just add up the permutations. Hint: use 1000(a, b, c or d) + 100(whatever hasn't been used) + 10(whatever hasn't been used) + (last digit left). Hope this helps.

Edit: I don't think that this is exactly what you were looking for, but another way to do this is by using a computer program. Use this Python program I made: https://repl.it/CRAc

Comment: Could you split your answer in paragraphs? It will greatly improve readability of your answer.